# Return rows ONLY if another column is equal to "Yes" Using dynamic table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

So I m trying to return rows of data in a dynamic table

Here's a picture below of the data, table name is "Assignments" and I've tried this formula

[image]

```
if(Assignments[Shipping]="Yes", Assignments[Name],"")
```

The issue with this formula is it returns blank cells, and I intend to use this in a data validation where I only want cells with values. I know that the =FILTER function can do this perfectly, but I will be sharing this excel file with someone who doesn't have 365 (they have 2019 and FILTER isn't supported).

Basically I only want to return names when the columns are equal to YES, I was able to get it working with and "IF" statement, but it returns blank cells, is there a way to return ONLY the rows equal to "yes" WITHOUT the blank rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a possible option using a Helper Table kind of column.
See the below screen-to-gif and check if this is something you want.

[image]

In my example sample Table is named as Table24.
In Cell H5 enter following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. It will be automatically enclosed in Curly Braces.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table24[Name],SMALL(IF(Table24[Shipping]="Y",ROW(Table24[Shipping])-ROW($F$4),9^99),ROW()-ROW($F$4))),"")
```

Drag it down up to the intended rows. Ideally the full length of your Assignments table and even extend further as much as possible.

Convert this data to Table. In my example it's named as Table4.

Create a Name in Name Manager and assign this Table[Column] to it. In my Example that Name is My_List.

[image]

Cell I5 has Data Validation. Now in Data Validation select List and put the following formula referring to this Name of Table4 (My_List)

```
=OFFSET(H5,0,0,MIN(IF(My_List="",ROW(My_List)-ROW(H5),9^99)))
```

If however you plan to copy this validation to multiple cells then better use Absolute reference.

```
=OFFSET($H$5,0,0,MIN(IF(My_List="",ROW(My_List)-ROW($H$5),9^99)))
```

[image]

Drop Down should now have only Filtered List, no blanks.
Hope this helps.

Just in case, a simpler version of formula in Data Validation List using SUMPRODUCT.

```
=OFFSET($H$5,0,0,SUMPRODUCT((My_List<>"")*1))
```